# Minzinc: Applying a constraint on each row of a 2D-array

Tags: arrays, minizinc

I am trying to apply a `regular` constraint on each row of a 2D array of int var:

```
enum ROW;
enum COL;
enum VAR_ENUM;
array[ROW, COL] of var VAR_ENUM: sequence;
include "regular.mzn"
constraint forall(r in ROW)(regular(sequence[r], ... other regular parameters))
```

I end up with the error `MiniZinc: type error: 2-dimensional array accessed with 1 expression`.

Is there a way to slice a 2D array? If not, how else could I apply a regular constraint on a large number of array variables?

Comment: Are you looking for `row(sequence,  r)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Row `r` of 2D-array `sequence` can be accessed by `row(sequence, r)`.